# jQuery script works locally - Breaks when transferred to server?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox, jscrollpane

I have two jQuery items that are working perfectly when testing locally but once moved to the server, start running into 2 browser specific issues.  I can break this into two separate questions if it helps.

The first issue is the jScrollPane plugin that is being used to allow styling of the scroll-bar on a couple of "overflow:scroll" divs in Firefox.  Annoyingly, the solution works absolutely fine for IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.  Again, when tested locally, it works as it should (including within Firefox), but when moved to the server, the functionality breaks.  The jScrollPane "plugin" is firing - It's adding the jspContainer, jspScrollable and jspPane per Firebug, but just isn't adding the scroll functionality in Firefox.  On screen, it shows as an overflow:hidden div.

The second issue is with a fixed position nav bar class change to .current based on section elements hitting the top of the viewport.  My solution works great in Firefox and Chrome, but isn't switching in IE.

EDIT - This script isn't working locally or on the server in IE.  It works perfectly in Chrome/FF

Unfinished working mock-up can be found at www.4SDesignStudio.com/new-projects/bwh/index.html

I'm locally hosting jQuery version 1.11.

Scrollbar Issue HTML:

```
 <div class="scroll-pane">  
                                <div id="main-tasting-menu">
                                    <div class="centered">
                                        <h2 style="margin:0; padding:0; ">Big Reds and Tasty Whites Menu</h2>
                                        <p style="margin:0; padding:0;">For our sweeter and champagne-esque releases, please click the "Bubbles &amp; Dessert Menu" to the right</p>    
                                        <br/>                               
                                    </div>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2010-viognier.jpg" alt="Big White House 2012 Viognier"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2012 Viognier | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Ripken Vineyard, Lodi - Single Vineyard Viognier</a></h4>
                                    <p>Our 2012 Viognier benefitted from a mild ripening season rewarding us with aromas of ripe melon and orange zest.  Cold fermentation and extended barrel aging then yield 
                                    beeswax and honey in the nose.  The extended barrel aging also gives us an extra-creamy mouthfeel to balance the crisp finish.</p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2009-lapsus.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2012 Lapsus | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">California Blend - 50% Viognier, 38% Roussanne, 12% Marsanne</a></h4>
                                    <p>Our 2012 Viognier benefitted from a mild ripening season rewarding us with aromas of ripe melon and orange zest.  Cold fermentation and extended barrel aging then yield 
                                    beeswax and honey in the nose.  The extended barrel aging also gives us an extra-creamy mouthfeel to balance the crisp finish.</p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2012-pinot-noir.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2012 Pinot Noir | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Ripken Vineyard, Lodi - Single Vineyard Pinot Noir</a></h4>
                                    <p>We loved this Pinot as a baby, and love it still, but as a teenager, it's ready to bound out into the world - Light, sparkly, fresh and not looking back.  We like its forward 
                                    leaning confidence and light-hearted humor.  As its parents, we are concerned about the short skirt and skimpy top.  It is the youngest child that we've ever allowed to leave home.  
                                    You can't keep them down on the farm after the've seen Paris.</p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2010-east-west-syrah.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2012 East-West Syrah | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Livermore Valley Blend - 100% Syrah, 2 Vineyards</a></h4>
                                    <p>This 2010 Syrah we call East-West Syrah because it marries Syrah from a hilly, Eastern Livermore Valley vineyard with a rocky stream-bed of a vineyard from the west side. The 
                                    mouth has a nice big syrah mouth feel, moderated by a little bit of butteriness in the mid-palate and finally, finishing with a taste of juicy blackberry.</p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2011-alfies-amalgamation.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#"><u>*Barrel Sample:</u> 2011 Alfie's Amalgamation | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Livermore Valley Blend - 40% Petite Sirah, 40% Zinfandel, 20% Cab</a></h4>
                                    <p>Great mouth-feel, blackberry, cherry and alspice in the nose is followed by big mouth-feel and a juicy finish in the mouth.<br><br></p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2009-zinfandel.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#"><u>*Barrel Sample:</u> 2012 Zinfandel | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Sblendorio Vineyard, Livermore Valley - Single Vineyard Zinfandel</a></h4>
                                    <p>Lighter and brighter than the 2011, the 2012 still maintains the style of a food-friendly Zin.  Cranberry and strawberry with hints of white pepper in the nose is followed by medium body 
                                    and long finish in the mouth</p>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2011-chateau-marion.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2011 Chateau Marion Bordeaux | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Livermore Valley Blend - 50% Cabernet Sauvignon, 50% Merlot</a></h4>
                                    <p>Bordeaux blend of eastern Livermore Cabernet and Merlot.  In our 2011 Chateau Marion, find mid-palate structure and spice from the Merlot and cherry, with a long juicy finish from the Cab.</p>
                                    <br/>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/je-2011-amoureux.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">2011 La Famille Des Amoureux | John Evan Cellars</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Livermore Valley Blend - 80% Cab, 20% Petite Sirah</a></h4>
                                    <p>The fourth in the Lovers Series, this Les Am continues the tradition of matching a masculine cab with it's feminine couterpart to achieve balance and structure.  The Lovers Series tracks John Evan's 
                                    and his wife Christina's relationship.  The newest milestone is a baby boy, born April 2nd.  A little bit of Petitie Sirah represents the new addition.  Like the little man himself, Petite Sirah 
                                    gives a big impact in a little package.</p>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>   
                                </div>
                                <div id="dessert-tasting-menu">
                                    <div class="centered">
                                        <h2 style="margin:0; padding:0; ">Dessert and Bubbles Menu</h2>
                                        <p style="margin:0; padding:0;">For our red and white releases, please click the "Big Reds &amp; Tasty Whites Menu" to the right</p>    
                                        <br/>                               
                                    </div>

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2007-liquid-amber.jpg" alt="Big White House 2012 Viognier"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Grand Cuvee | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4>Sparkling Wine</h4>
                                    <p>This delightfully dry, sparkling wine was bottled specifically for our Big White House Sparkling Cellars Label.  We like the tiny bubbles, creamy mouth feel and crisp, dry 
                                    finish.  Equivalent in dryness to a French "Brut", this is a terrific sparkler for celebrating any occasion.  Try this in a "kit" mixed with the Sherry (two parts Cuvee, one part 
                                    Late Harvest Viognier).</p>
                                    <p style="color:orange">NEED CORRECT LABEL IMAGES</p><!-- Need correct labels -->

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2007-liquid-amber.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Peche Mignon | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Peach Sparkling Wine</a></h4>
                                    <p>You've all loved our dry sparkling wine and now John Marion made a special release for his grandmother Eva.  Our sparkling wine is kissed with peach and is sure to become a 
                                    favorite of everyone.  Still plenty of tiny bubbles with a creamy mouth feel and crisp dry finish.  Try this in a "kit" mix with Ma Cherie.</p>
                                    <p style="color:orange">NEED CORRECT LABEL IMAGES</p><!-- Need correct labels -->

                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/labels/bwh-2007-liquid-amber.jpg" alt="XXXXX"/></a>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Ma Cherie | Big White House</a></h3>
                                    <h4><a href="#">Sherry-Style, Late Harvest Viognier</a></h4>
                                    <p>Sherry is often described as the most under-rated of traditional wines.  Our aging regime follows the traditional approach, using not-quite-full barrels.  The flor controls the 
                                    oxidation and allows for the formation of a variety of aromas including Turbinado sugar, dried apricot, caramel, orange blossom and toasted almonds.</p>
                                    <p style="color:orange">NEED CORRECT LABEL IMAGES</p><!-- Need correct labels -->
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tasting-menu {
margin-top: 0;
padding-top:1em;
padding-left:.25em;
height: 24.5em;
line-height:1em;
background:rgba(00,00,00,.5);
border-radius:8px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.tasting-menu h3{
    color:rgba(224, 145, 50, 1);
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-size:1.1em;
    }

.tasting-menu h4{
    font-size:.9em;
    font-weight:400;
    }

.tasting-menu p {
    font-size:.75em;
    font-weight:300;
    margin:auto 1em .5em 16%;

    }

.tasting-menu img {
    width:12.5%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1.5em;     
    }

/* Creates toggled hidden and visible menus using Javascript for Main Menu and Desert/Bubbles Menu */
.button-switches input {
    width:85%;
    border-radius:3px;
    background: rgba(224, 145, 50, 1);
    }

    .button-switches input:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        background: rgba(00,00,00, .5)
        }


#main-tasting-menu {
    display:block;
    }

#dessert-tasting-menu {
    display:none;
    }
/*  jQuery Scrollbar fix for Firefox browser */     
    .scroll-pane {

        position:relative;
        height:24.5em;
        overflow: scroll;
        padding-bottom:1.5em
    }
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

// Cached variables to avoid multiple jQuery calls
var $mainLinks = $('.main-links');
var $headerLogo = $('.header-logo');
var $mainTastingMenu = $('#main-tasting-menu');
var $dessertTastingMenu = $('#dessert-tasting-menu');
var $menuSwitch_1 = $('#menu-switch1');
var $menuSwitch_2 = $('#menu-switch2');

// Plugins
$('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
$('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();

// Event handlers

$menuSwitch_1.on('click', function(event) {
  $mainTastingMenu.toggle('show');
  $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
});

$menuSwitch_2.on('click', function(event) {        
  $mainTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
  $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('show');
});


$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

  $mainLinks.fadeIn();
  $headerLogo.fadeIn();

} else {

  $mainLinks.hide();
  $headerLogo.hide();
}


var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
    idx = $('section.marker').sort(function (a, b) {
            return top - $(b).offset().top;
          }).first().index('section.marker'),
    el  = $('.main-links li a').eq(idx);

if (!el.hasClass('current')) {
    $('.main-links li a').removeClass('current');
    el.addClass('current');
}
});

});</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - No errors listed.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap scroll spy will work the navbar issue, where the links are '#link' to point to an 'id="link"'.

When the id object moves to the top, the menu active class will change to match.

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6q3LpjL7/

```
<!-- add class to body tag:-->
<body  class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="60">

<!-- Example of href in navbar -->
<li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>

<!-- ID attribute to match href in navbar --L
<h3 id="section-2">Section 2</h3>


<!-- jQuery to scroll page using scrollTop and scrollSpy -->
$(function(){   
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(){
        var pathName = location.pathname;
        var thisPathName = this.pathname;
        var locHost = location.hostname;
        var thisHost = this.hostname;       
        if( pathName == thisPathName && locHost == thisHost ){ 
            var target = $(this.hash);          
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if(target.length){              
                $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: $( target ).offset().top - 65 }, 1250 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I suppose looking at another plugin is an option (and I'll take a look at Scroll Spy for future use), but I'm more interested in figuring out why the current setup is having browser specific issues.